# Mule ESB Consume Multiple REST Services

Tags: web-services, rest, mule, esb, anypoint-studio

My API name is A, and I have to call 2 REST services in my API.

I was able to call one REST service, and tried calling 2nd REST service using Scatter-Gather but no luck.

Here is my flow diagram for calling single REST service
[image]

Based on service response, I am using Choice and transforming message to my Service schema and things are cool up to this point, but I have few fields left in my schema, those need to fetched from other REST call.  So.., How can i consume two REST services and transform them into my API schema?

[image]

I have tried with scatter-gather, first call POST and second call is GET and I was able to map some details from first and some details from second REST call to my API schema, but How can I display my final output ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using Variable transformers to store the results of the calls. I was able to achieve something similar using the following:
[image]

Note the use of sub-flows, each of which start with an HTTP Request Connector.

I'd be happy to clarify anything here if needed, just let me know!

Comment: Hi Deckeresq, thanks for your reply, I have updated the Q, can you please check it once.

Comment: Hey @John, can you save the payload into variables? After each HTTP Request Connector, just have a Set Variable which stores the resultant payload into a flowvar. Then after the Scatter-Gather you can do a Set Payload and reference the two flowvars.

Comment: Hi Deckeresq, I have created two variables after http requests and named as one, two and values are #[payload] for both. After scatter-gather I have placed set payload and given the value as #[flowVars.one];#[flowVars.two] but finally its giving null null as output, am I doing any thing wrong ? sorry its very new for me, thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Do your flowVars get set with the right values?

Comment: I have used custom strategy class and was able to see those two flowVars after scatter-gather, with names one and two, I am able to get the payloads of 2 services by setting #[flowVars.one] or #[flowVars.two] in set payload, but I want to transform these two payloads into my new service api, but if I use transform message its not showing the flowVars again, but set Payload is able to access those flowVars.

Comment: You may be able to do Set Payload and make a map like this:

value = #[['one':flowVars.one,'two':flowVars.two]]

Then your Transform Message operator will be able to see these data in the resultant payload.